# action bar background is shown in middle of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have changed the background of the action bar but it looks like this:

(I cant post image because I dont have more than 10 reputation)

I have the stock action bar and my actionbar background is shown in middle of the screen. I dont know how can I describe it better.

Do you know what is the problem?

here is my styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.geniboys.sosyaaal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geniboys.sosyaaal.loginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.geniboys.sosyaaal.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.geniboys.sosyaaal.SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.geniboys.sosyaaal.SignUp2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.geniboys.sosyaaal.LogoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_logo"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbackground"
    tools:context=".loginActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/loginEmail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/loginSifre"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:text="@string/loginEmailhint"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/loginGiris"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="kayitOl"
        android:text="@string/loginKayit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/loginSenKimsin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action bar style probably isnt being being used as your theme does not link to it, the parent for the ActionBar style should also be changed:

Add this inside your AppBaseTheme:

```
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
```

Change action bar style declaration to:

```
  <style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
```

Then post your layout xml and we'll see if we can help you further

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it isnt shown in middle of the screen but the background of the actionbar doesnt change. Btw which layout do you want me to post?

Comment: The layout to whichever activity is showing this weird behaviour plus the manifest pelase

Comment: Unfortunately I can't spot the problem, it is working for me with a very similar setup to your own. I use parent="Theme.AppCompat" for my AppTheme parent. Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: The problem can be with the background, what is the dimensions of your actionbar background?

Comment: Mine is a drawable with a gradient, so no dimensions

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? can you accept this answer or add the right answer to close this question and get it off the unanswered list, thanks!